# How Do I iterate through d3.select(this)

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm afraid I still don't understand d3-object.
I created d3-elements and assigned `select.on("mouseover", onGraphicMouseOver)` events to them.
Now I'm in my function and have `this`.

If I log `this` I get my straight svg-string:

```
<g id="a29" style="touch-action: none; -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);">
  <line class="hotwater graphic" x1="270" y1="110" x2="540" y2="110" id="g29"></line>
  <line class="hotwater graphic" x1="270" y1="120" x2="540" y2="120"></line>
</g>
```

So far, so fine.

Now I want to wark with the lines, like assigning classes to them and for this, I want to iterate through them.
What is the best way to do?

My first idea:

```
for (var i = 0; i < this.childNodes.length; i++) {
    this.childNodes[i].classList.add("graphicmouseover");
}
```

But isn't there a simpler way, using d3.js.
And if so, how can I find such informations by myself. I now played around with d3 since many weeks but don't have a really complete idea of the concept. Perhaps someone knows a more informative documentation than the original, for a dumb like me :(
I really appreciate a helpful hint, so I don't have to annoy you with these noob-questions.

Thanks Carsten

Update because of request:
I load the svg-string of the inner element (here both lines) as text out of a database. Then:

```
function loadGraphicIntoEditor(svgGraphics, editor) {
//svgGraphics are the json-recordsets, editor is the d3.selected svg-area

  for (var i = 0; i < svgGraphics.length; i++) {
    var graphic = svgGraphics[i];

    const graph = editor.append("g")             //appending the g-tag to the svg-area
        .attr("id", "a" + graphic.Id.toString())
        .html(graphic.SvgString)                 //the string <line...></line>
        .on("mouseenter", onGraphicMouseEnter)
        .on("mouseover", onGraphicMouseOver)
        .on("mouseout", onGraphicMouseOut)
        .on("mousedown", onGraphicMouseDown)
        .on("dblclick", onGraphicDblClick)
        .on("contextmenu", onGraphicContext)
        .call(d3.drag()
            .on("start", graphicDragStart)
            .on("drag", graphicDragging)
            .on("end", graphicDragEnd));
    d3.select(graph.node().childNodes[0]).attr("id", "g" + graphic.Id.toString());
  }
}
```

FINAL UPDATE:

This is my solution now:

```
function onGraphicMouseOver(d, i) {
    d3.select(this).selectAll('.graphic').classed("graphicmouseover", true);
}
```

...life could be so easy :)

thank you guys

Comment: Can you show how you have created the lines and g elements?

Comment: update my post.  Of course the drawing of a new line is a bit more complex. Is it relevant for you, Andrew?

Comment: Idiomatically you wouldn't use a loop to append a set of anything in d3 like this. D3 was designed with data binding in mind - which generally would require an enter selection. You could avoid the loop with an enter selection: this would allow easier manipulation of the elements using the bound datum - `d` in your event listener, avoid searching for all `.graphic` elements each event. This makes later modifications or alterations much easier too. If you want I'll add an answer with this approach.

Comment: Hi Andrew, everything is welcome to better understand d3js. Many thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try something like:

```js
var lines = d3.selectAll('line.hotwater');
//console.log(lines);

lines.each(function(d,i) {
  //console.log(i, d, this);
  //console.log(this);
  d3.select(this)
    .attr("stroke", "black")
    .attr("stroke-width", "5px")
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<svg width="1000" height="1000" style="background:#ff0000">
  <g id="a29" style="touch-action: none; -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);">
    <line class="hotwater graphic" x1="270" y1="110" x2="540" y2="110" id="g29"></line>
    <line class="hotwater graphic" x1="270" y1="120" x2="540" y2="120"></line>
  </g>
</svg>
```

Output:

[image]

NOTE: I set the svg background to red in the HTML

But then I used `d3.selectAll('line.hotwater');` to select both of our lines.
And then used `lines.each()` to loop over them.
And used `d3.select(this)` to turn that into a d3 selection which we can then modify like usual:

```
d3.select(this)
    .attr("stroke", "black")
    .attr("stroke-width", "5px")
```

This adds the black stoke and the 5px stroke width to the lines so that we see them on the svg.

I am using d3.js V5.x here but I think the API has been like this for a few versions.

**Update:** as OP clarified

Easiest method is just to use d3’s selectAll:

`select(this).selectAll('.graphic').classed("graphicmouseover", true);`

This is essentially doing a descendent querySelectorAll of “this” (from the event) and then looping over and setting the class for each of those selected. D3 manages this for us with its select all.

**Update after understanding the OP's problem more fully.**

Problem is that the events are attached to the group and not the lines.

But I think there is a way to achieve this with a pattern like:

```
const graph = editor.append("g")             //appending the g-tag to the svg-area
        .attr("id", "a" + graphic.Id.toString())
        .html(graphic.SvgString);                 //the string <line...></line>

    console.log(graph.selectAll('line.graphic').size()); //gives the size of the selection

    graph.selectAll('line.graphic')
        // .attr('stroke', 'blue')
        .on('click', onClick);
```

I tried to make a minimal reproducible example from the OP's code here: https://codepen.io/Alexander9111/pen/MWwmVLr

Also here:

```js
const svgGraphics = [
  {
    Id: '29',
    SvgString: `<line class="hotwater graphic" x1="270" y1="110" x2="540" y2="110" id="g29"></line>
               <line class="hotwater graphic" x1="270" y1="120" x2="540" y2="120"></line>`
  }
]

const editor = d3.select('svg');

loadGraphicIntoEditor(svgGraphics, editor);

function onClick(d,i){
  console.log('clicked');
  //console.log(this); //or console.log(event.target);
}

function loadGraphicIntoEditor(svgGraphics, editor) {
//svgGraphics are the json-recordsets, editor is the d3.selected svg-area

  for (var i = 0; i < svgGraphics.length; i++) {
    var graphic = svgGraphics[i];

    const graph = editor.append("g")             //appending the g-tag to the svg-area
        .attr("id", "a" + graphic.Id.toString())
        .html(graphic.SvgString);                 //the string <line...></line>

    console.log(graph.selectAll('line.graphic').size());

    graph.selectAll('line.graphic')
        // .attr('stroke', 'blue')
        .on('click', onClick);
        // .on("mouseenter", onGraphicMouseEnter)
        // .on("mouseover", onGraphicMouseOver)
        // .on("mouseout", onGraphicMouseOut)
        // .on("mousedown", onGraphicMouseDown)
        // .on("dblclick", onGraphicDblClick)
        // .on("contextmenu", onGraphicContext)
        // .call(d3.drag()
        //     .on("start", graphicDragStart)
        //     .on("drag", graphicDragging)
        //     .on("end", graphicDragEnd));
    d3.select(graph.node().childNodes[0]).attr("id", "g" + graphic.Id.toString());
  }
}
```

```css
line {
  stroke: black;
  stroke-width: 5px; 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<svg width="1000" height="1000" style="background:#ff0000">

</svg>
```

Comment: Hi Alex, thank you for the each-idea, I was missing. There could be any other svg-element like circles or rects but all have the class graphic. With your approach, I could select all graphic and assign them the new class. You are right, you couldn't see the lines wiht white background. In my site, the lines got their color by css, I forgot. Yor approach helps. Thank you!

Comment: ...that doesn't work out of the box. I think it could be a problem that this is already in useof the event? But I found a much easier way: `d3.select(this).selectAll('.graphic').classed("graphicmouseover", true);`

Comment: Yeah that makes sense. I had to guess the use case a bit and wasn’t sure in what context you had “this”. You are essentially then doing a descendent querySelectorAll and iterating over them and setting the class for each (d3 is doing this with the selectAll). If my answer helped please consider to up-vote. Thanks! Glad it worked out :)

Comment: Shit... now I have the group to assign the mouseover but if I like to "select" only one of the lines, I don't get the line, that catched the click-event, because the <g> takes it. Any ideas?

Comment: So you mean, the event is attached to the ``<g />`` tag, which might contain more than 1 line inside it? So now when you try to click on either of the lines inside, it calls the event for the parent `<g />`` tag and so rather than being a specific event for each line it is a group event for the group of lines?

Comment: Exactly... But I think, I will not work out this case. grouped is grouped. In a polyline you also couldn't select only one segement. There will be an ungrouping routine later, that will save such groups in seperate records, so then every line is single in its group... Now I count the childNodes and if more than one, "select all" elements `d3.select(this).selectAll('.graphic').classed("selectedGraphic", true);`  BTW, is there a property that counts the elements in a d3.selection? `d3.select(this).selectAll('.graphic')` something like length?

Comment: Check out my updated answer and codePen: https://codepen.io/Alexander9111/pen/MWwmVLr - I think you can add the events to the lines individually using the same kind of `graph.selectAll('line.graphic')` pattern. Yeah you can get the size of the selection like `console.log(graph.selectAll('line.graphic').size());` using `.size()` I added to my answer.